# How to draw a ROC curve for each Fold in cross validation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, roc, caret

I am evaluating my model using K fold cross validation and I would like to draw a ROC curve for each of the folds and **show them ALL TOGETHER**.

I'm using the R programming language and I'm going to attach some code I'm testing that I found here on Stack Overflow:

```
t_control <-
  trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 5,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = T,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )

model_forest <- caret::train(diabetes ~., data = train_set,
                         method = "rf",
                         metric = "ROC",
                         trControl = t_control)

for_lift <- data.frame(Class = model_forest$pred$obs, rf = model_forest$pred$R, resample = model_forest$pred$Resample)
lift_df <-  data.frame()
for (fold in unique(for_lift$resample)) {
  fold_df <- dplyr::filter(for_lift, resample == fold)
  lift_obj_data <- lift(diabetes ~ rf, data = fold_df, class = "pos")$data
  lift_obj_data$fold = fold
  lift_df = rbind(lift_df, lift_obj_data)
}
lift_obj <- lift(diabetes ~ rf, data = for_lift, class = "pos")

ggplot(lift_df) +
  geom_line(aes(1 - Sp, Sn, color = fold)) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Fold"))
```

Execution of this code triggers the following error:

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

And the error occurs when the loop is executed.

Before executing the above lines of code (the ones corresponding to the model) I have done the following:

```
names(df) <- c("pregnant","glucose","pressure", "triceps","insulin","mass","pedigree","age","diabetes")
df$diabetes <- ifelse(df$diabetes == 0, "neg", "pos")
df$diabetes <- as.factor(df$diabetes)
str(df)

#store rows for partition
partition <- caret::createDataPartition(y = df$diabetes, times = 1, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

# create training data set
train_set <- df[partition,]

# create testing data set, subtracting the rows partition to get remaining 30% of the data
test_set <- df[-partition,]

str(train_set)
```

Comment: can you share ```dput(train_set)``` ?

Comment: You can download the dataset from this repository in Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/code/mayankagrawalds/predict-diabetes-multiple-ml-models/data

I will attach in the question everything I do before training the model so you can run the same code as me

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on different sites https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/111849/50620